# How to run Windows commands in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, windows, command

Is there a way to put windows commands in C++ program.
I am a newbie so your help will be very much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: There's probably a function for whatever specific command you were thinking of, and possibly a standard or Boost one at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try system function from cstdlib.

http://www.kev.pulo.com.au/pp/RESOURCES/cplusplus/ref/cstdlib/system.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [system()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function from <cstdlib>7. Although be aware that it will probably create a cmd.exe window. If you don't want that then you can use the windows specific [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.